# How to show data onpaste realtime

Tags: jquery

I have problem onpaste function when I first paste data on textarea
display not show realtime but click paste data again display can show
data

How do it ,first click paste show data realtime

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="jquery.js"></script> 
<div id="previewie"><div id="Displaytitle"></div></div>
<textarea id="title"class="click"style="overflow:hidden;border:1px #ffccff solid;width:399px;height:auto;resize:none"cols="45"rows="3"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#title").bind({
    paste: function () {
        var title = $("#title").val();
        $.post("re.asp", {
            ste: title
        }, function (data) {
            $('#Displaytitle').html(data);
        })
    }
});
</script>
```

result:

```
re.asp <%=request("ste")%>
```

Comment: `$("#title").bind("paste",function(){})`

Comment: $("#title").bind("paste",function(){}) not working you can try not work

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe this:

```
$("#title").on("input paste",function(){
    //rest of code
});
```

Working example:

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nAZbm/1/)